# fetching recipient from html form

Tags: php, html, forms

Please help i've been stuck on this for 2 days. i want my PHP form handler to fetch recipient email address from my html form. instead of typing someone@yahoo.com in the PHP

**HTML FORM CODE**

```
<input type='hidden' name='recipient' id='recipient' value='someone@yahoo.com'>
```

**THE PHP CODE**

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);

error_reporting(E_ALL);
/*
Tested working with PHP5.4 and above (including PHP 7 )



*/
require_once './vendor/autoload.php';

use FormGuide\Handlx\FormHandler;

$pp = new FormHandler(); 

$validator = $pp->getValidator();

$validator->fields(['name','email'])->areRequired()->maxLength(50);

$validator->field('email')->isEmail();

$validator->field('comments')->maxLength(6000);

$pp->sendEmailTo('someone@yahoo.com'); // ← Your email here

echo $pp->process($_POST);
```

Comment: You probably just can use `$pp->sendEmailTo($_POST['recipient'])`

Comment: That would also mean that people can use your form to spam others. If all emails should go to the same email address, it actually makes much more sense to have it as a config-param in your PHP application. Remember that you should never trust user data.